# Transpose dataframe with datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to transpose dataframe that has datetime index.

```
             1    2
2015-01-01  100  20
2015-02-01  100  50
2015-03-01  100  78
```

However after trasnposing when I try to select coluns from these dataframe I'm getting keyerror:

```
df.T[['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01']]
```

Error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01'], dtype='object', name='CohortMonth')] are in the [columns]"
```

How can I select them so that error is not yielded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because selecting by list is necessary same types - here datetimes in list for maching `DatetimeIndex in columns`:

```
#if necessary create DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df = df.T[pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01'])]

print (df)
   2015-01-01  2015-02-01
1         100         100
2          20          50
```

Comment: I get this error: `KeyError: "None of [Index([(2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-02-01 00:00:00)], dtype='object', name='CohortMonth')]`

Comment: @AlexT - hmmm, can you test `df = pd.DataFrame({'1': {pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 100, pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'): 100,
                         pd.Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'): 100}, 
                         '2': {pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 20, pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'): 50,
                               pd.Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'): 78}})` ?

Comment: Okay first one worked, there was something wrong with my bracket placement, thanks.